# React selection option value change the variable data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to become a front-end developer, so I'm creating a project with companies info. I tried to find on YouTube and here, but still I couldn't understand.

I want to use on Change to show the result, but How I pass the option value to the variable?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class BusinessCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      company: null,
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let companyCod = "MSFT"; // I want receive the option value here
    let companyUrl =
      "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=" +
      companyCod +
      "&apikey=YOUR-API-KEY";
    let response = await fetch(companyUrl);
    let data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ company: data, loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <div>loading</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <select>
          <option value="MSFT">MSFT</option>
          <option value="AAPL">AAPL</option>
          <option value="IBM">IBM</option>
        </select>

        <h1>Company: {this.state.company.Name}</h1>
        <h1>Symbol: {this.state.company.Symbol}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great that you want to become a front-end developer! The code in `componentDidMount` will only be run once when the component is first mounted. Do you want to run it when the select option changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the `countryCode` in your component state, and move the `componentDidMount` code into a separate function that you call both in `componentDidMount` and when the select changes.

**Example**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class BusinessCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      company: null,
      companyCode: "MSFT"
    };
  }

  loadCompany = async (companyCode) => {
    let companyUrl =
      "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=" +
      companyCode +
      "&apikey=YOUR-API-KEY";
    let response = await fetch(companyUrl);
    let data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ company: data, loading: false });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadCompany(this.state.companyCode);
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const companyCode = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ companyCode });

    this.loadCompany(companyCode);
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <div>loading</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <select
          value={this.state.companyCode}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
          <option value="MSFT">MSFT</option>
          <option value="AAPL">AAPL</option>
          <option value="IBM">IBM</option>
        </select>

        <h1>Company: {this.state.company.Name}</h1>
        <h1>Symbol: {this.state.company.Symbol}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```